# Print words with matching pattern

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

I want to print words with matching pattern using grep/sed/awk/etc from file in Linux.
 I checked grep/sed/awk all prints line, I want only words from file.

Example:

I have file test.txt with following contents:

```
root@root:~]#cat test.txt
Notification are enabled Notification:445 Mode: valid Bookmark are enabled Bookmarks:556    Mode: Invalid Question are enabled Question:667 Mode: Unknown
```

Then I want to print only words with matching pattern *tion

```
Notification
Notification
Question
Question
```

Is there a way to do this in command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with GNU grep:

```
 grep -oE "\w*tion" test.txt
```

Output:

```
Notification
Notification
Question
Question
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F '[: ]' 'index($1, "tion") {print $1}' test.txt
Notification
Notification
Question
Question
```

Comment: The input file is one line.

Comment: Input file format was changed by OP after I submitted the answer. I never post these answers without testing first myself.

Comment: OK.  To tell the whole story, I felt puzzled while posting my comment, my bad I didn't check the edit by the OP...

Comment: @me Make a knot in my handkerchief: when I see a "strange" answer, always check the history of the question.

Comment: No worries @gboffi: sometimes these answers look stupid after such a major edit by OP